# How to Decode htmlentities in yui TextAreaCellEditor

Tags: javascript, yui

I am facing problem with yui TextAreaCellEditor.

Below yui statements opens the editor with save and Cancel button on clicking the yui column.

```
var myTextareaCellEditor = new YAHOO.widget.TextareaCellEditor();

var myColumnDefs = [ 
{key:"title",label:"Title", sortable:true ,editor: myTextareaCellEditor},
];
```

Now my problem is when ever I specify title and save in database for example my title is "`text&data<new>`".
It is properly getting saving but when I open the editor containing the title text.
It display like "`text&amp;data&lt;new&gt;`".
I wanted to remove html entities from editor.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**TextareaCellEditor** has a Event called "**Focus**", When the editor is initailized and focus is on it, the Focus function is called, You can make use of it.

```
var myTextareaCellEditor = new YAHOO.widget.TextareaCellEditor({
      focus:function(e){
          var textVal = myTextareaCellEditor.textarea.value;
          textVal = decodeTEXT(textVal) ;
          myTextareaCellEditor.textarea.value = textVal; 
      }
});
```

**myTextareaCellEditor.textarea.value** : will give the value that appears in the text area. This value you can decode using the decodeText() function and replace the textarea value.

```
function decodeTEXT(textVal){
    textVal = textVal.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
    textVal = textVal.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
    textVal = textVal.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
    textVal = textVal.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    textVal = textVal.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");

    return textVal;
}
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy coding :)